# D3D9 CreateDevice() fails on Windows 10 when creating a multihead device

Tags: windows-10, directx-9

When calling [IDirect3D9::CreateDevice](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb174313%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) with the BehaviorFlags D3DCREATE_ADAPTERGROUP_DEVICE in order to create a fullscreen [multihead device](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb147217%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (with 2 or more monitors attached) the function returns D3DERR_INVALIDCALL, when running the application on Windows 10 (build 1511, or build 10240).

The same code works fine on Windows 7 (on a multitude of different machines), and also on Windows 8.1 (with the latest updates). Also creating individual D3D9 devices (fullscreen) for each attached monitor to the graphics adapter works fine on Windows 10.

D3D9Ex by the way shows exactly the same behavior. Can anyone point me to a working D3D9 multihead example that works on Windows 10? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I observed the exact same behaviour with "CreateDevice".
But when you use "CreateDeviceEx" it works ... well ... almost :-(.

You may now create the device and use it, but under some circumstances (especially if you use the same resolutions as the desktop already had) you wont see anything and "Present" will continuously return "S_PRESENT_MODE_CHANGED". But if you now switch the second monitor to some other resolution via ResetEx end then switch back to desktop resolution - voila it works. I put that on on a key I can press after initialization:

```
        const int idx = 1;
        int OldWidth = D3DPresPar[idx].BackBufferWidth;
        int OldHeight = D3DPresPar[idx].BackBufferHeight;
        D3DPresPar[idx].BackBufferWidth = 1280;
        D3DPresPar[idx].BackBufferHeight = 720;
        D3DDispMode[idx].Width = 1280;
        D3DDispMode[idx].Height = 720;
        FailCheck(pD3DDevice->ResetEx(D3DPresPar, D3DDispMode), "ResetEX");
        D3DPresPar[idx].BackBufferWidth = OldWidth;
        D3DPresPar[idx].BackBufferHeight = OldHeight;
        D3DDispMode[idx].Width = OldWidth;
        D3DDispMode[idx].Height = OldHeight;
        FailCheck(pD3DDevice->ResetEx(D3DPresPar, D3DDispMode), "ResetEX");
```

And after pressing the key it suddenly works. Weird, eh?
I confirmed this behaviour on multiple computers with nvidia, amd and intel grafics adapters. So the bug seems to be on microsoft side.

Conclusion: Theoretically it should work but there is some annyoing bug in windows 10 multihead initialization.
With some weird tricks you can achieve what you want, but these tricks are just too weird to use in production.